# ABCD is a trapezoid. Given EF=5 (E and F - midpoints of AB and CD), BD=10 & Area of ABCD = 48 cm^2, find AC.

Tags: geometry

I ran into some difficulties with a problem. Could somebody please help me?

In the figure below, we have the trapezoid $ABCD$. $E$ and $F$ are the midpoints of $AB$ and $CD$ respectively. If $EF=5$cm, $BD = 10$cm and the area of the trapezoid is equal to $48$ square centimeters, then what is $AC$ equal to?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Oh ok, I'm very sorry then. I'll make sure to do it like that next way! Thanks for the advice. :)

Comment: Let draw line through E and middle of AD till intersection with continuation of CD. Then we know two sides and area of formed triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the intersection of $BD$ and $EF$ be $X$. It's easy to prove from similar triangles that $AXC$ is a straight line, and many side lengths are in ratio. Let $r$ be the ratio

$$r = \frac{AB}{CD} = \frac{BX}{DX} = \frac{EX}{FX} = \frac{AX}{CX}$$

Let $a$ be the area of $\triangle FDX$. Then the the $6$ triangles partitioned by $BD$, $EF$ and $AC$ have areas:

$$\begin{align*}
\text{Area of }\triangle CFX &= \text{Area of }\triangle FDX = a\\
\text{Area of }\triangle DAX &= \text{Area of }\triangle BCX = 2ar\\
\text{Area of }\triangle AEX &= \text{Area of }\triangle EBX = ar^2\\
\text{Area of }ABCD &= 2a + 4ar + 2ar^2\\
48&= 2a(1+r)^2\\
a &= \frac{24}{(1+r)^2}
\end{align*}$$

The area of $\triangle FDX$ is also equal to

$$\begin{align*}
a &= \frac12XD\cdot XF \sin \angle DXF\\
&= \frac12\cdot\frac{BD}{1+r}\cdot \frac{EF}{1+r} \sin\angle DXF\\
\frac{24}{(1+r)^2}&= \frac{25\sin\angle DXF}{(1+r)^2}\\
\sin\angle DXF &= \frac{24}{25}
\end{align*}$$

From here, there are two solutions depending on whether $\angle DXF$ is acute or obtuse. Focus on $\triangle FDX$ and $\triangle CFX$,

$$\begin{align*}
\cos \angle DXF &= \pm\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{24}{25}\right)^2} = \pm\frac 7{25}\\
XC^2 &= \left\|2\vec{XF}-\vec{XD}\right\|^2\\
&= \left\|2\vec{XF}\right\|^2 + \left\|\vec{XD}\right\|^2-2\left(2\vec{XF}\right)\cdot \vec{XD}\\
&= 2^2\left\|\vec{XF}\right\|^2 + \left\|\vec{XD}\right\|^2-4\left\|\vec{XF}\right\| \left\| \vec{XD}\right\|\cos\angle DXF\\
&= \frac{2^2\cdot5^2+10^2\mp4\cdot5\cdot10\cdot 7/25}{(1+r)^2}\\
&= \frac{200\mp56}{(1+r)^2}\\
XC &= \frac{14\mp2}{1+r}\\
AC &= (1+r)XC = 14\mp 2\\
\end{align*}$$

$AC=12\text{ cm}$ if $\angle DXF$ is acute, or
$AC=16 \text{ cm}$ if $\angle DXF$ is obtuse.

Comment: Thanks a lot! From a comment someone posted above I understand that I should have been more explicit about what I have tried so far and what exactly confuses me. However, I am grateful for taking your time to answer my question given the circumstances. Thanks once again!

Comment: @FrederickKaddin then would you edit your question to include what you have tried and what exactly confused you?